# fast powering algorithm is slower than native powering - python

Tags: python-3.x, algorithm, cryptography, number-theory

I've been trying to implement the fast powering algorithm into python code, but it turned out to be slower than the native approach, where's the problem?

```
import timeit
test  = """
def Power(base, power, mod):
    base_to_the_powers = [base]

    temp = list(bin(power)[2:])
    temp.reverse()

    for i in range(len(temp)-1):
        base_to_the_powers.append(base_to_the_powers[i]**2%mod)
    values_to_multiply = [base_to_the_powers[index]  for index,i in enumerate(temp) if i == '1' ]
    x=1 
    for value in values_to_multiply: 
        x = (x* value) % 1000

    return x 

Power(3,218,1000)

"""
test2 ="""
result = (3**218)%1000
"""
print(timeit.timeit(test),"\n", timeit.timeit(test2))
```

Comment: Python's `pow` uses binary exponentiation. You won't see the boost from modding it each time with a small power like 218. But do note that `pow` does take a mod argument - `pow(base, power, mod)`

Comment: Thanks, that was it, I tried a larger power and there was a significant difference!!

Comment: Beware of spooky speedups. For instance, Java's `BigInteger` uses tricks like JVM "internals" that simply run the best CPU instructions available in native mode. Those kind of instructions is almost impossible to compete against.